# remove all non-alphanumeric characters from lua string

Tags: lua, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

I checking string for a non-alphanumeric char.

```
if(str:match("%W")) then
  --make str alpha-numeric
end
```

How to remove all non-alphanumeric chars from string using lua?

Comment: `str = str:gsub('%W','')`

Comment: Egor, just turn this into answer ;)

Comment: It works great. Thank you @EgorSkriptunoff and please make it as answer :)

Comment: @PaulKulchenko - Answer must contain at least 30 characters.  I don't have so many :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff how hard can it be to add a sentence of explanation to get over 30 characters?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I'm sure you can add a link to `gsub`, which will easily make it over the threshold. Oh, well; I guess I can do that myself :)

Answer (score 11):

Use [gsub](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) (as suggested by Egor Skriptunoff):

```
str = str:gsub('%W','')
```

Answer (score -1):

just make it like this
you forgot +

```
if(str:match("%W+")) then --if it contain alpha
     number = str:match("%d+")
     alpha = str:match("%W+")
 end
```